# How can I add a react Component To the DOM with jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, reactjs, jsx

This is prob a super easy question but, I want to add components to a grid with react and jquery.
gridGame is a black 100px by 100px square and I want to add items into it. Im using rows (a variable) witch is a number from 1-9 to and sumbing it in to the `gridGame-${rows}` as seen here,so it can auto update the correct row to join. value should be: gridGame-${row} (what ever number row is from 1-9) and then I want to add a component inside gridGame called <Test /.> (witch is declared up-top in unseen parts of the code).

The function below has jquery that I thought would work in this situation:

```
 function = (rows) => {
console.log(`joining ${rows}`)
let value= $(`#gridGame-${rows}`);
  
value.append("<Test />");
value.css("background-color", 'brown');
$(".create-coinflip-box").css("display", "none");
```

}

The css background change works but the value.append does not display the react component.

Here is the React Component inside the <Test /.>:

```
    import React from 'react';
import StatusIcon from './img/image.png';
import Player1Icon from './img/image.png'


class newGame extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return(
            <div>  
              HELLO
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default newGame;
```

I honestly have 0 idea on how this doesn't work.

Thanks for the help :)

Comment: *"react and jquery"* - That's the root of the problem right there.  You should be using one or the other, but trying to use both is going to be extremely difficult and require you to have very in-depth understandings of the inner workings of both and to write a ton of logic to get around those inner workings.

Comment: Should I revert back to Document.getElementByID ways of adding Components?

Comment: If you're using React, you should use React.  You can certainly make changes to the DOM directly with jQuery or plain JavaScript, but those changes aren't going to be known to React.  And those changes would be to the HTML DOM, not React's virtual DOM.  There's no `<Test>` element in HTML, so you'd need to use the actual resulting HTML instead.  If you want to use React, then whatever you're trying to do would be much easier with React.

Comment: I tried writing a return statement and returning the <Test /.> react component instead of having the Jquery there but that also did not work. What other ways can I use React to render components?

Comment: *"What other ways can I use React to render components?"* - You're essentially asking "How do I use React?"  There are a variety of tutorials to get you started.  Based on the question above the only real advice to give is to focus on what those tutorials are showing you in React and not to try to impart your own functionality with jQuery.

Comment: Allow me to Rephrase. if the rows function(rowsFunc) is inside another function(function2) and I want to return a component from rowsFunc and function2 is a onClick to a button is that my issue. That I cant render a component from a button?

Comment: because all of the other methods had a function in the render() {
{this.function} --- The videos

<button onClick={this.func} > Button </button>  -- Mine

}

Comment: In React you wouldn't "render a component from a button".  The action of the button would be to update the state.  And the React component renders based on the current state.  So for example if you have some value in state which says how many times to render the `<Test>` component, then in the render function you'd have a loop which renders `<Test>` that many times.  And in the button click handler you'd update that state value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This answer was from David in the comments. The problem for me was I was trying to render a component through a button and not the actual render its self.

The solution is to instead make the button change the state witch Updates the React DOM. Then just have a if statement that checks the state then display the component.

His comment explains much better and fixed the problem for me.